# what is the difference between my code and the solution that checks if two binary trees are identical?

Tags: python, tree

I am writing code to check if two trees are the same, but I need help to determine what is different between the code that I have written and the actual solution.

here is my code:

```
class Solution:
    def isSameTree(self, p: TreeNode, q: TreeNode) -> bool:
        if not p or not q:
            return False
        if not p and not q:
            return True
        if p.val != q.val:
            return False

        return self.isSameTree(p.right,q.right) and self.isSameTree(p.left,q.left)
```

And here is the correct code:

```
class Solution:
    def isSameTree(self, p, q):
        
        if not p and not q:
            return True

        if not q or not p:
            return False
        if p.val != q.val:
            return False
        return self.isSameTree(p.right, q.right) and \
               self.isSameTree(p.left, q.left)
```

Comment: `if not p and not q:` will never be true in your version, because the previous `if` would already have dealt with this (stronger) condition. The order is important.

Answer (score 0):

The condition `if not p or not q:` contains the case when p and q are None and in this case the two trees are obviously the same when in your code you return `False`.